Esta función de suma me devuelve más decimales que los operandos
Public Sub Rendimiento()
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim xN As String
    For I = 2 To Worksheets("Legajos").Range("J1").Value
        xN = Worksheets("Legajos").Cells(I, 9).Value
        With Worksheets(xN)
        J = .Cells(1, 4).Value - 1
        If J > 5 Then
            .Cells(2, 10).Value = Round(SumaLitros(xN, J), 3)
        End If
        End With
    Next I
End Sub

Private Function SumaLitros(xHoja As String, K As Integer) As Single
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Single
    With Worksheets(xHoja)
    For I = 6 To K
        J = J + .Cells(I, 7).Value
    Next I
    SumaLitros = J
    End With
End Function


(ejecuto el sub Rendimiento y este llama a la función SumaLitros)
No sé qué pasa acá
Ejemplo, en la hoja donde en J2 me pone el resultado de 6 decimales, los valores a sumar son
66,777
75,407
67,777
215,37
0
184,777

Si sumamos (o usamos =SUMA(G6:G11) sería 610,108 pero la función que hice en VBA me da 610,107971
Las celdas en si  tienen los resultados que aparecen, no están redondeados y ni siquiera tienen más dígitos en el libro de donde copio los datos
Por si preguntan por qué uso VBA para la suma, es porque suma desde el 2º valor de la tabla hasta el último, que puede variar de largo dependiendo la hoja

Eso es un problema y no es un problema.. simplemente redondea el resultado al valor que queres... hay una gran respuesta en el sitio que te explica porque los valores flotantes (como el single) no son precisos. mira esta pregunta

Gracias. El problema era que ninguno de los sumandos tiene más de 3 decimales

que vos veas.. pero una cosa es lo que vos ves, y otra la representacion interna.. lee lo que te pase ;)

Tal vez esto responda tu pregunta ¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?.

En Excel (y en muchos otros programas) no es lo mismo lo que vemos (es decir, el formato) que el valor real que almacenamos. Mira este ejemplo:

Como verás, he puesto en 2 celdas el valor 4.5 y lo he sumado en la tercera. Hasta aquí todo correcto.
Mira lo que pasa si yo selecciono las 2 primeras celdas y le digo que aplique formato redondeando a cero decimales:

Pues que visualmente, lo que vemos es que 5 + 5 = 9 y eso es mentira. Pero nos está engañando el formato aplicado. Excel, visualmente, siempre va a mostrar el formato que le digas pero digamos que en su motor (o en segundo plano) en realidad siempre va a coger el valor real de la celda y usará todos los decimales disponibles (En este ejemplo sigue haciendo 4.5 + 4.5 = 9)
Pues en tu caso es lo mismo. Que tú visualmente en la celda veas 66.777 no significa que ese sea el valor verdadero (podría ser, por ejemplo 66.77699999. Con VBA pasa lo mismo y tiene en cuenta todos los decimales disponibles (ahora mismo no recuerdo si el máximo de decimales es 14, 15 o 19 o cuantos pero por ahí debe rondar).
TRUCO: Para ver el valor real que tiene la celda, selecciona la celda y mira el valor en la barra de fórmulas:

Si quieres forzar que el valor (y no el formato) de un cálculo sea redondeado a un número de decimales específicos tienes que usar la función REDONDEAR. En VBA tienes la función ROUND
En tu caso, entiendo que quieres forzar que la función SumaLitros devuelva siempre 3 decimales, pues simplemente cambia la última línea:
SumaLitros = Round(J, 3)

